# Are Loki's abilities considered to be on par with super powers by other Asgardians?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In the MCU, are Loki's abilities considered to be on par with super powers by other Asgardians? Or are they considered to be regular abilities honed to an unusually high level?

For example, is Loki's magic considered to be the equivalent of Batman - a regular person who is stronger and faster than average because he trains a lot? Or the equivalent of Superman - someone who has abilities so far beyond everyone else that they are unapproachable by a normal human?

I'm specifically asking this in the context of characters being unaware that Loki isn't from Asgard.

Comment: Related: [Is Thor more than an Asgardian?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100125/58193) and [Are the Asgardian Gods and the Asgardian People the same thing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/256950/58193)

Comment: Just to note that: skills!=innate-abilities.

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket, that a skill was something that you were good at, not something innate. For example, using a lightsaber to dual is something that anyone can do through practice For example General Grievous is a skilled lightsable user, but using the force is something that you need to be born able to do, as such Grievous can't do it. It's not a skill that he can gain.